# Accessing Excel formulas from clipboard in HTML / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, excel, clipboard

E.g.
I got a cell with the formula LEN(A3). Pasting it to an HTML text area or an text editor will just paste the value.

Is there a way to access the formula in a cell from the clipboard instead of the actual value?

Comment: can you provide some code!? where actually your html cell look like!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are literally more than two dozen clipboard formats used by Excel. I just looked most of them in binary view (my ClipMate clipboard extender has a binary option in the viewer) and guess what?  I didn't see formulas anywhere.  Doesn't look like they're on the clipboard. That's not to say that you can't REQUEST the data by "pasting" an OLE object.  i.e. if you were a word doc, pasting a spreadsheet, you'd get the embedded spreadsheet, which would contain the data. But that's done mostly outside of the clipboard.

Comment: "Doesn't look like they're on the clipboard."  But they must be, because Excel is capable of copying and pasting formulas in cells where only the value is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the value from the Excel formula bar rather than from the cell grid.
OR
Change the Excel grid view to show formulas rather than calculated values, then cut and paste

Comment: i think where the question may come from is that when you copy&paste a cell within Excel, it copies the formula (or its derivative), while the OP observed behavior under which the value is copied. Since Excel seems to be able to distinguish between value and formula, hence his question.

Comment: Acutally I want to copy multiple cells, so copying from formula bar won't work.

I will check the suggestion to change the grid view to show formulas.

I think for a desktop application it should be possible to access formulas from the clipboard using COM, ActiveX or something like this.

Comment: Hence my second suggestion: Tools/Options/View and check the Formulas box. Then do your cut and paste